# How can I find Time from defined URL using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am working in `Java` and using `Jsoup`. I want to find `Time` from the below url. I tried with these but unable to get it. The time lies in `span` tag but under the `id(timestamp--time  timeago)`  I am trying with it but I do not know what is the problem.

```
Document doc;
            Elements lin = null;
            String url = "http://www.dawn.com/news/1277133/this-is-how-pakistanis-around-the-country-are-celebrating-independence-day";
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20*1000).userAgent("Chrome").get();
                lin = doc.getElementsByClass("span.timestamp--time  timeago");
//              System.out.println(lin);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            int i=0;
            for(Element l :lin){
                System.out.println(""+i+ " : " +l.text());
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
lin = doc.getElementsByClass("span.timestamp--time  timeago");
```

with

```
lin = doc.select("span.timestamp--time.timeago");
```

Output:

```
0 : Aug 14, 2016 04:29pm
1 : Aug 14, 2016 12:39pm
2 : Aug 14, 2016 01:34pm
3 : Aug 14, 2016 01:37pm
4 : Aug 14, 2016 04:19pm
5 : Aug 15, 2016 01:11am
6 : Aug 15, 2016 08:49am
7 : Aug 16, 2016 12:32pm
```

From the wording in the [API](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByClass-java.lang.String-) `getElementsByClass` only accepts a single classname. So in this case `lin = doc.getElementsByClass("timestamp--time");` gives the same output, but if you want to select by multiple classes than [`select`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) is the better choice.

Comment: In the source code `<span class='timestamp--time  timeago' title='2016-08-24T00:38:07+05:00'><span class='timestamp__calendar'>Aug 24, 2016</span>` the `timeago` is not a different class as you used IN `span.timestamp--time.timeago`([.timeago] Working fine with your suggestion) but `<some blank spaces>` . Should we decide that if there is a space after any class name then it will be a `class` name? As you used this `doc.select("span.timestamp--time.timeago");` instead of this `doc.select("span.timestamp--time   timeago");`

Comment: The `timeago` IS a different class (though there is no definition in the css file, might be used in the same way we use it, to be able to select it), spaces are the deviders for the `class` attribute in html. In chrome you could use the developer tools (Ctrl+Shift*I) and when you select the node you are looking for in the Elements tab, chrome will show you a hover on the page with a css selector (separated by dots). Please also mark this answer as solution, if it resolved your question.

Comment: Oh Yeah. I reached now. Sure. Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is wrong. Use this instead:

```
lin = doc.select("span.timestamp--time.timeago");
```

Comment: Why not this `doc.select("span.timestamp--time   timeago");` ? Is `timeago` a different class name?

Comment: Your CSS query is looking for a tag named timeago under span with that class. If you want to search by multiple class use: .class1.class2.class3